# Providing multiple formats (ogg,mp3) while creating Audio dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, dynamically-generated

When using html5 audio you can provide multiple formats/codecs with:

```
<audio controls>
   <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
   <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"> <-- secondary format here
   Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

I create Audio with

```
var audio = new Audio('pathtomyaudio/myaudio.mp3');
audio.load();
```

Is there a way to dynamically provide another extension such as ogg?

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: True, didn't run into this,thank you. But i would still like to know if this is possible?

Comment: Whoever -1'ed this question: Provided possible duplicate doesn't suit my need: it manipulates DOM directly by creating sources. I can do that easily enough. But how about with new Audio such as I need to do it?

Comment: I didn't -1, but the solutions in the linked question apply to your situation. You don't even need to add it to the DOM: http://jsfiddle.net/54JrC/

Comment: Really sorry about the music. It was the first Google hit for "sample mp3" :(

Comment: OPS: this is NOT a duplicate. He is asking about the 'new Audio()' way, the article you've linked explains the <audio> tag!

Comment: No. There is no way to provide multiple sources when creating a `new Audio` instance in javascript.